# Spring Boot: Controller - 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this webapp

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/update")
public class Update{


    @RequestMapping(value = "/tracking_number", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateTrackingNumber(@RequestHeader(value = "order_id")String orderId,
                                                       @RequestHeader(value = "tracking_number")String trackingNumber,
                                                       HttpSession httpSession){

        //url: localhost:8080/update/tracking_number
        //this one works perfectly

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/order_products", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateOrderProducts(){

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("i hope to see this text");

    }

}
```

SpringBootApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainCore extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(MainCore.class, args);
    }

}
```

WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException{

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.web.foo");
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

WebMvcConfigurer:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.web.foo.controller")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

The structure:

```
com
 - web
 - - foo
 - - - controller
 - - - - Update.java
 - - - MainCore.java
 - - - AppInitializer.java
 - - - WebConfig.java
```

When I access `localhost:8080/update/tracking_number` it works perfect.

But when I access `localhost:8080/update/order_products` it no longer works and gives the response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1618404297125,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/update/order_products"
}
```

Comment: Can you try `@RestController` annotation instead?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar, yes. I also removed the parameters of method, to make it as simple as possible. But still.

Comment: did you provide the proper request body?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar, yes, but I also removed the parameters from method. I updated my quest.

Comment: They're both POST requests.. are you POSTing to both?

Comment: @roflcopter1101, yes of course. For wrong method should get `405 Method Not Allowed`, but I get `404 Not Found`

Comment: @KunLun do you use spring suite tools?

Comment: @Boug, I don't know what is that :) I'm using Intellij IDEA

Comment: @KunLun try doing a maven clean install and try again

Comment: This is interesting case, because both should work, can you check if `@PostMapping` works for second URL?

Comment: Also, try checking with this property in your properties file `logging.level.org.springframework.web=trace` , does your controller methods and endpoints are being mapped or not.

Comment: !!! FOUND IT !!! My problem was solved by `Invalidate Caches` from Intellij IDEA. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @KunLun please post this as an answer and approve it, so that people can use it in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is running directly from Intellij IDEA.

So, in my case, the solution was to `Invalidate caches`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the request has Content-Type header. Also in @RequestMapping add consumes = "application/text" or "application/json"  whatever is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try add @ResponseBody methods of updateOrderProducts